# Getting out a string and inserting it into an array separately

Tags: arrays, reactjs, string, function, object

I have an array like this

```
["Billboard,Television"]
```

and I want something like this

```
["Billboard", "Television"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few other ways:

```js
let str2 = ["Billboard,Television", "have,an,array,like,this"]
let sol = str2.toString().split(",")
console.log(sol)
```

```js
let str2 = ["Billboard,Television", "have,an,array,like,this"]
let sol = str2.join(",").split(",")
console.log(sol)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) for that:

```js
const bla = ["Billboard,Television"];

const result = bla.flatMap(el => el.split(','));
console.log(result)
```